# not entering in all the for loop in if statement

Tags: python

I'm new to python and im trying to make a small program that checks if the number is prime/non prime and odd/even at the same time, the fact that i wrote `for i in range(2,num):` and inside that condition there is `if (num % i) == 0:` to check if its prime or not, but it is only checking the `i=2` at the first time and after i put the first number and it increments, what im asking is that why it isnt checking for `i=3..4..5..` to see if its prime or not

Because when I test it and put number `21` the first time, it says that its prime and if i put `21` the second time it tests on `i=3` and says its not prime.

And another problem, i wrote `while (num != 0):` so the program should stop after entering a value `0` but its still running till i enter it multiple times to stop.

```
num = int(input("Inserez un nombre pour s'avoir s'il est pair/impair, premier/non premier. (0 pour finir) \n"))
while(num != 0):
    if (num > 1):
        for i in range(2,num):
           if (num % i) == 0:
               #print(num,"is not a prime number")
                if(num % 2 ==0):
                   print(num, "est non premier et pair")
                   num = int(input("Un autre numero : "))
                else:
                    print(num, "est non premier et impair")
                    num = int(input("Un autre numero : "))
           else:
               #print(num,"is a prime number")
                if(num % 2 == 0):
                   print(num, "est premier et pair")
                   num = int(input("Un autre numero : "))
                else:
                    print(num, "est premier et impair")
                    num = int(input("Un autre numero : "))
       
    elif (num <0):
       print("On voudrais un numero positif!")
       num = int(input("Un autre numero : "))
       
    elif (num == 1):
        print(num, "est premier et impair")
        num = int(input("Un autre numero : "))
```

I used the source code from [programiz](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/examples/prime-number) and modified it to check if its odd or even,

> The Original Code :

```
num = 407

# To take input from the user
#num = int(input("Enter a number: "))

# prime numbers are greater than 1
if (num > 1):
   # check for factors
   for i in range(2,num):
       if (num % i) == 0:
           print(num,"is not a prime number")
           print(i,"times",num//i,"is",num)
           break
   else:
       print(num,"is a prime number")
       
# if input number is less than
# or equal to 1, it is not prime
else:
   print(num,"is not a prime number")
```

Example : [image]

Tested on : [onlinegdb](https://www.onlinegdb.com/online_python_compiler)

Comment: The first quick observation is that you took out the `break` which was useful and important. You should probably perform some debugging of your own -- add `print` statements at various places to see what the variables contain, and see where your script is going wrong.

Comment: The `else` parts down near the bottom will ask for a number but then do nothing with it.

Comment: Your code is logically incorrect. See the first else statement where you have commented out 'number is prime' print statement. What its going to do? You need to check all the numbers before deciding if its prime or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The break is important!

In your code the for loop was looping, but was never breaking until it reached your original number. You need to break out of the for loop once a prime number is found. If the loop completes without breaking, the else statement will be run. The user input should then be outside of the loop and after the else statement.

As a side note, in Python, brackets are not required on if and while statements, although I did not edit those.

```
num = int(input("Inserez un nombre pour s'avoir s'il est pair/impair, premier/non premier. (0 pour finir) \n"))
while (num != 0):
    if (num > 1):
        for i in range(2, num):
            if (num % i) == 0:
                # print(num,"is not a prime number")
                if (num % 2 == 0):
                    print(num, "est non premier et pair")
                else:
                    print(num, "est non premier et impair")
                break
        else:
            if (num % 2 == 0):
                print(num, "est premier et pair")
            else:
                print(num, "est premier et impair")
        num = int(input("Un autre numero : "))

    elif (num < 0):
        print("On voudrais un numero positif!")
        num = int(input("Un autre numero : "))

    elif (num == 1):
        print(num, "est premier et impair")
        num = int(input("Un autre numero : "))
```

Comment: so my code was okay but I didnt wrote ```break```, just to be sure, in every loop in Python we need to break? and re-check from ```i=2``` for example?

Comment: We do not need to `break` in every loop in Python, if you look at your code. But in this situation, after we've found that the number is not prime, we do not have to continue searching, so we `break`. The other issue was the positioning of your second `else`, it should be after the `for`, not the `if`. Indentation is important in Python.

Answer (score 0):

You only need to get input once per while loop, not per for loop so put that at the end of your while loop and get rid of any other occurrence of input.

Besides that, you're missing the break statement that gets you out of your for loop.

```
num = int(input("Inserez un nombre pour s'avoir s'il est pair/impair, premier/non premier. (0 pour finir) \n"))

while num != 0:
    if num > 1:
        for i in range(2, num):

            if num % i == 0:
                # print(num,"is not a prime number")
                if num % 2 == 0:
                    print(num, "est non premier et pair")
                else:
                    print(num, "est non premier et impair")
                break

            else:
                # print(num,"is a prime number")
                if num % 2 == 0:
                    print(num, "est premier et pair")
                else:
                    print(num, "est premier et impair")
                break

    elif num < 0:
        print("On voudrais un numero positif!")

    elif num == 1:
        print(num, "est premier et impair")

    num = int(input("Un autre numero : "))
```